# What does $|x|^2$ mean in this proof that the Schwartz space is a subspace of $L^p$?

Tags: fourier-analysis, schwartz-space

The following is supposed to be a proof that the Schwartz space is contained in $L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$ for $1 \leq p <+\infty$:

> Given $f \in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^n),$ there is a constant $K>0$ such that
> $$|f(x)| \leq \frac{K}{1+|x|^2}$$
> for every $x \in \mathbb{R}^n.$
> Hence,
> $$|f(x)|^p \leq \frac{K^p}{(1+|x|^2)^p} \leq \frac{K^p}{1+|x|^2} \in L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$$
> and we conclude that $f \in L^p(\mathbb{R}^n),$ as desired.

Now, I don't know what $|x|^2$ means here. If it is the norm, then the bound for $|f(x)|$ is true, but for $n=2$ the function $1/(1+|x|^2) = 1/(1+x_1^2+x_2^2)$ is not integrable on $\mathbb{R}^2.$ Help will be appreciated.

Comment: I think you're interpreting $|x|$ correctly as the norm of $x$. Perhaps the author meant to use $$\frac{K}{1+|x|^{2n}}$$

Comment: Presumably the proof was written for $n = 1$, and when it was generalised, that point was overlooked and left unchanged. Make it "there is a constant $K > 0$ such that $$\lvert f(x)\rvert \leqslant \frac{K}{(1 + \lvert x\rvert^2)^n}\,\text{"}$$ and it works for all $n$.

Comment: @Daniel Fischer Okay, and how does one prove that $1/(1+|x|^2)^n$ is indeed integrable?

Comment: You could use polar (spherical) coordinates, or note $$\frac{1}{(1 + \lvert x\rvert^2)^n} \leqslant \prod_{k = 1}^{n} \frac{1}{1 + x_k^2}\,.$$ The right hand side there is clearly integrable since each factor is integrable over the corresponding line.

Comment: Very nice. Thanks!